# Border of an HTML table Row is not displaying in jsPopUp Window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

Here is the situation If i am applying Border for a table row it is not showing i used it inline also but no difference in output:

**Code:**

```
<style>
.dispTab{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%;text-align:left;line-height:30px;
}
.dispTab tr{
    border:1px solid black;
}

</style>
<table id="dispTab" class="dispTab" >
    <thead >
        <tr style="border:1px solid black">
            <th class="leftalign">Date
            </th>
            <th class="leftalign">Time
            </th>
            <th class="leftalign">Location
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<tr><td>01/05/2013<br/>Wednesday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>02/05/2013<br/>Thursday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>03/05/2013<br/>Friday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>04/05/2013<br/>Saturday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>05/05/2013<br/>Sunday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>06/05/2013<br/>Monday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>07/05/2013<br/>Tuesday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>08/05/2013<br/>Wednesday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>09/05/2013<br/>Thursday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>10/05/2013<br/>Friday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>11/05/2013<br/>Saturday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>12/05/2013<br/>Sunday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>13/05/2013<br/>Monday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>14/05/2013<br/>Tuesday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>15/05/2013<br/>Wednesday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>16/05/2013<br/>Thursday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>17/05/2013<br/>Friday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>18/05/2013<br/>Saturday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>19/05/2013<br/>Sunday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>20/05/2013<br/>Monday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>21/05/2013<br/>Tuesday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>22/05/2013<br/>Wednesday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>23/05/2013<br/>Thursday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>24/05/2013<br/>Friday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>25/05/2013<br/>Saturday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>26/05/2013<br/>Sunday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>27/05/2013<br/>Monday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>28/05/2013<br/>Tuesday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>29/05/2013<br/>Wednesday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>30/05/2013<br/>Thursday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr><tr><td>31/05/2013<br/>Friday</td><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">No Meetings</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: rows cannot be styled, instead put the border on the th element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got Answer:**

```
.dispTab{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:30px;
    border-collapse:collapse 
}
.dispTab th, .dispTab td{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Apply the border to cells, not rows.
- If you don't want vertical cell separator border, turn the `border-left` and `border-right` off.
- If you want the table not "clumsy", collapse the borders

See the CSS:

```
.dispTab{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.dispTab th, .dispTab td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 0 none;
    border-right: 0 none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RT6WZ/)

Add border-collapse:collapse

```
.dispTab {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:30px;
    border-collapse:collapse 
}
```

Comment: u r answer is ok but i need vertical border also...now it is coming i posted the answer...

Comment: ya u r right............but u missed one thing we have to use border-collapse there also right... i done it now it is coming..........

Comment: if you won't apply border-collapse there result will be same. check this one http://jsfiddle.net/RT6WZ/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
.dispTab{
   border:1px solid black;
   width:100%;
   line-height:30px;
   border-collapse:collapse 
}
.dispTab td {
    border:1px solid black;
 }
```